# Django and celery DatabaseError: DatabaseWrapper

Tags: django, celery

I build a scraper and the price needs to be updated every 12 hours or so and i use celery to do it, but i get an error after the task is received:

*django.db.utils.DatabaseError: DatabaseWrapper objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object with al
ias 'default' was created in thread id 48931120 and this is thread id 89001448*

```
@shared_task
def update_price():
    scraper = Scraper.objects.all()
    for i in scraper:
        price = amazon_scraper(i.link)
        i.update(last_price = price, last_checked = timezone.now())
        time.sleep(18)
```

/settings.py

```
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'update_price': {
        'task': 'hackaton.tasks.update_price',
        'schedule': datetime.timedelta(seconds=120),
    },
}
```